# Create post status notification method for all pipelines

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mattermost

thanks in advance for the help.

For our project, for which we use Jenkins, I'm working on a shared library to house all methods for our different pipelines (3 different ones).
Currently I'm facing an issue, that I don't really know how to solve.

I configured the jenkins-mattermost-plugin for the project. Ideally, I'd like to create one method for the `post` task in Jenkins that takes `currentBuild.currentResult` as an argument and returns the corresponding condition block and its message.

Ex:

- if success:

```
  success {
    mattermostSend(...success build notification)
  }
}
```

- if failure:

```
  failure {
    mattermostSend(...failure build notification)
  }
}
```

- etc.

The problem is not writing the method itself, but when to call it in the pipeline.
I can't call it in a `stage` block, not without any block wrapper.

I hope this makes sense what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function in always post-condition:

```
   post {
        always {
                mattermostSend("${currentBuild.currentResult}")
        }
    }
```

Then inside mattermostSend create condition which depending on the build result will send the required message.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes the way you advised is definitely the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please accept this answer. :)

Comment: oh sorry, I thought I had